# Unable to locate Michael mission

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I’ve completed 26 mission.  There are no numbers for any of the characters except for Michael, which has a 1.  Going through the map I cannot find any missions available for Michael.  Not sure what to do next.  Btw I’ve completed the pilot training.

Comment: Hey, welcome on Arqade SE, please take [the tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) and read [the help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) if in need of guidance. I can't help you as I don't play GTA 5, but I guess it would help others to answer if you could indicate in a more precise way which missions you have previously completed.

Comment: Sadly is impossible to answer this question without more information. On GTA V, missions don't have a number assigned because there are multiple choices that can add or remove missions from the story.